# How to scroll modal to replace Div/h4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, modal-dialog

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var y = $("#pointed").scrollTop();
        var title = $("#subTitle");
        if (y > $("#hdr").height()) {
            if (!title.data("old")) {
                title.data("old", title.html()).html("<a href='#'></a>").find("a").text("new title");
                title.find("a").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.scrollTo(0, "fast");
                });
            }
        } else if (title.data("old")) {
            title.html(title.data("old")).data("old", null);
        }
    });
```

The code Above doesn't work.
Pointed is ID modal header and hdr is ID header of website. and subtitle is  id of title(`<h4 id="subtitle>title<h4>`)..and i want to make a scroll modal from pointed to hrd and than replace title of subtitle with new title.

Comment: Check your tags. Java != javascript.

Comment: @KevinWorkman yes :)

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have problem on this code.Please Help Me Please . Thank you before.